# seo friendly url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, permalinks

i know that this question was already posted a lot of time, i ve already search but i could not find what i need.

i'm working on my htaccess to add seo freindly link, for example:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^list$ list.php [L]
```

that work perfectly, the problem apper when i try to add vars, for exmpale i need that the url: **pages.php?id=terms** become: **page/terms**

so i've try in many way but don't work, this is what i try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^list$ list.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/ pages.php?x=$1 [L]
```

PS: what is the difference between **+FollowSymLinks** and **-MultiViews**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `QSA` flag:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^list$ list.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?x=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.
- Information about [Apache's content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html).
- `+FollowSymLinks` makes Apache follow symbolic links.
- `-MultiViews` make turns off content negotiation

**For CSS/JS/image:**

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. OR else You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thank you now the seo-link work (domain.com/page/terms) but the included file (like css) are not loaded. i have added "RewriteBase /" in my htaccess, but nothing change. how i can do?

Comment: is possible to append after the id the full title of the page? for example: domain.com/page/terms/page-title-in-this-format but in the htaccess the only param to use is the first (in this case "terms") and the htaccess just ignore the rest